# What blend equation is System.Drawing.SolidBrush using?

Tags: opengl, gdi, alphablending, blending, direct3d11

I have some GDI code that's drawing semi-transparent triangles using System.Drawing.SolidBrush. I'm trying to reimplement the code using a proper 3D rendering API (OpenGL/Direct3D11), but I'm not sure what blend equation to use for these triangles to get the same output as the original GDI code.

I assume it's something relatively simple like additive blending (func=GL_FUNC_ADD, eq=GL_ONE,GL_ONE) or interpolation (func=GL_FUNC_ADD, eq=GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA), but neither seems to look quite right. This is almost certainly to a bug in my new code, but I want to make sure I'm working towards the correct target before I continue. Does anybody know the appropriate blend equation?

**EDIT**: Here's the relevant C# code, stripped of context:

```
using System.Drawing;
SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha,red,green,blue));
Point[] points = ...;
Graphics g;
g.FillPolygon(b,points);
```

My question is, what color will actually be written, in terms of the brush's RGBA and the destination pixel's RGBA? All the docs I can find just say "use alpha to control the Brush's transparency" or something equally vague; I'm curious what the actual blend equation is.

Comment: What is the "GDI code" that you're trying to reimplement?

Comment: It's some image-processing code from a long-departed coworker that I'm trying to revive and integrate into a new, non-GDI project. The specifics are proprietary, but not terribly relevant to the question. I've added a snippet of the relevant code, though, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.compositingmode(v=vs.110).aspx), `System.Drawing.Graphics` has a property named [`CompositingMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.compositingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) which can be either `SourceOver` or `SourceCopy`.

The default one is `SourceOver`, which

> Specifies that when a color is rendered, it is blended with the background color. The blend is determined by the alpha component of the color being rendered.

As I have tested, the blend strategy used here is [alpha composition](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Alpha_compositing), which determines the pixel value in the area *image A over image B* by the following equation:

[image: Alpha composition equation]

Here α<sub>a</sub> and α<sub>b</sub> are the normalized alpha value of image A and image B; C<sub>a</sub> and C<sub>b</sub> are the RGBA values of image A and image B; C<sub>o</sub> is the RGBA value of the output image.

Comment: Note that if both alpha values are zero, this comes out to `(0, 0, 0, 0) / 0`, i.e. mathematically undefined, which GDI+ (at least according to my tests) handles by making the result `(0, 0, 0, 0)`.